# on the Projective Nullstellensatz

Tags: algebraic-geometry

In his book Algebraic Curves, Prof. Fulton says the following with regard to the projective Nullstellensatz:

[image]

I am not sure what he means by "to make an exception" with respect to the irrelevant ideal. I do see the truth of the sentence that follows that statement ("In particular,..."), but i can't see
how the two connect.

Comment: My mistake.  I was not aware of that terminology.

Comment: The exception is that the irrelevant ideal, although maximal in $k[X_1,\dots,X_{n+1}]$, doesn't correspond to a point of $\mathbb{P}^n$. (I think that this is why it's called "irrelevant".) I think that the "in particular" is referring to the projective versions of the usual corollaries, and not particularly to the exception. (?)

Comment: @BenBlum-Smith: I like your explanation of why its called "irrelevant".